# Apply bootstrap.css/js ot Epub file

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, epub

I use [Epub.js](https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js) for render epub files in web-browser. But I need use bootstrap styles in book(also needed popovers). Is this possible?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. Epub 3 format has the annotation.

```
<p>This sentence contains a <a href="#note" epub:type="noteref">commented phrase</a>.
</p>
<aside id="note" epub:type="footnote">This is the comment.</aside>
```

The epub.js wasn't hide `<aside>` then I set in epub stylesheet.css

```
aside { 
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

and now it working normally.